# Does NotificationCenter have an event for didUnlockDevice?

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, notificationcenter

Is it possible to register for notifications pertaining to Device unlocks?  Ideally, I'm trying to count the number of biometric (FaceID / TouchID) unlocks performed by a User.

More generally, does Apple have a list of events to which an app can subscribe for notifications?  I *think* [this might be it](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification/name) ... but I'm not sure.

Comment: listen for screen lock / unlock ??

Comment: Not public. Check out this if you want use private methods: https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/How-to-detect-device-Lock-Unlock-status-in-iOS